# Unable to edit or delete fields using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have installed phpMyadmin 4.5.0.2 on Mac book Pro. I am not able to delete rows from my table using "Delete" button nor edit values by double clicking on them. The SQL generated to do this not correct where in it is omitting where clause like below

```
DELETE FROM Dimn_Observation WHERE LIMIT 1
```

If I manually type SQL statements it executes Ok. but I am not able to select few rows directly and neither modify or delete rows.

How do I solve this issue.

Comment: Are you using MAMP by chance?

Comment: Not MAMP it is separate installation of phpMyadmin

Comment: What MySQL version are you using, please?

Comment: Mysql Server version: 5.6.27 MySQL Community Server

Comment: are you using table name with CAPS letter? 

That should be issue